# Prevent Replacing Escaped Sequence in JavaScript Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

JSFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/A3vg6/20/

```
    var regex = /(?:window|scope|data|owner)(?:\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)*/gi;

    var path = [];
    var vars = [];

    var ms = txt.replace(regex,
        function (match) {
        var nv = "v" + (path.length + 1);
            if (match.indexOf("owner.")==0) {
                match = match.substr(6);
            }
            path.push(match);
            vars.push(nv);
            return nv;
        }
        );
```

I am getting output

```
data.x + data.y + $data.z + xdata => v1 + v2 + $v3 + xv4
```

But correct output should be,

```
data.x + data.y + $data.z + xdata => v1 + v2 + data.z + xdata
```

So anything starting with $ should be escaped, as well as if data appears after any character should not be replaced. There are only 4 keywords, window, scope, data and owner, these words needs to be replaced with variables.

I hate regular expressions, but this has to be regex as it will contain complex sequence such..

```
data[ Calculate( x, data.y)] => v1[ Calculate(x,v2)]
```

We have little success now, but I have problem with new sequence

```
data[data['x']] + data.x + data.y + $data.y + xdata
```

Becomes

```
v1v2['x']] +v3 +v4 + data.y + xdata
```

But it should be

```
v1[v2['x']] +v3 +v4 + data.y + xdata
```

**Answered:**

http://jsfiddle.net/A3vg6/44/

Works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/(^|[^\w])(?:window|scope|data|owner)(?:\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)*/gi
```

and change your function to:

```
var ms = txt.replace(regex,
        function (match, prefix) {
            if (prefix == "$") return match.substr(1);
            var nv = "v" + (path.length + 1);
            match = match.substr(1);
            if (match.indexOf("owner.")==0) {
                match = match.substr(6);
            }
            path.push(match);
            vars.push(nv);
            return prefix + nv;
        }
        );
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/A3vg6/40/

Comment: Thanks, but xdata gets replaced too, xdata should remain as xdata.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is eating up square bracket or round brackets. Check my updated question.